# Azure Devops Wiki Entity Relationship Diagram

Tags: azure-devops, wiki, azure-devops-wiki

I'm new to Azure Devops but have found items online that suggest it is possible to create Entity Relationship Diagrams in an Azure wiki page using mermaid. For example in the link below.

https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues/1338

I can create items with mermaid code however when I use the erDiagram text and click to load diagram, I just get an "Unsupported diagram type" error. I'm not sure if this is something wrong in my text or if I need to upgrade mermaid(?). I have no clue about all this really as I'm new to it and a quick google seems to imply this is a common problem that hasn't been solved yet.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: Since it is related to mermaid, not Azure Devops. You have to create a new ticket under [mermaid](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues).

Comment: @Mr Qian, this question does pertain to Azure DevOps. The product's Wiki implements some specific Mermaid version. It is presently behind the current Mermaid release so it can be confusing to use as some newer diagrams and syntax are not supported.

Comment: https://mermaid.live/ then into README.md in the azure devops repo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems **erDiagram** is not presently supported by Azure DevOps Wiki's mermaid implementation. I get the same error with an *erDiagram* that renders fine in the [Mermaid Live Editor](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/#/edit/eyJjb2RlIjoiZXJEaWFncmFtICAgIFxuICAgIENVU1RPTUVSIHx8LS1veyBPUkRFUiA6IHBsYWNlc1xuICAgICIsIm1lcm1haWQiOnt9LCJ1cGRhdGVFZGl0b3IiOmZhbHNlfQ). I've had trouble with other diagram types too.

This page, [Markdown Syntax...Mermaid diagrams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#add-mermaid-diagrams-to-a-wiki-page), indicates only three diagram types are presently supported:

- Sequence diagrams
- Gantt Charts
- Flowcharts

Comment: I should have also noted, the example at the link you provided (issue #1338) fails. I presume the feature was once partially implemented but later retracted. Mermaid works. Azure DevOps Wiki's implementation does not.

Comment: Thanks Scott, what a shame, hopefully it will be available one day.

Comment: Please go here and vote for Microsoft to upgrade Mermaid:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/mermaid-support-for-class-diagrams-and-state-diagr/883356

Comment: I've opened MS Documentation Issue #10956: 'Add Mermaid diagrams to a Wiki page' links to incorrect Mermaid documentation.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/10956

Comment: As of today, Wiki supports the following Mermaid diagram types:
Sequence diagrams
Gantt charts
Flowcharts
Class diagram
State diagram
User journey
Pie chart
Requirements diagram